# comprension de la siguiente función con ajax y jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

No comprendo del todo como funciona este metodo necesito una explicación de su funcionamiento sobre todo de la linea,

> url:BASE_URL+'main/get/'+tabla+'/'+campo+'/'+valor

```
function load2(tabla,campo,idSelect,valor){
        var select = $('#'+idSelect);
    //alert(BASE_URL+'main/get/'+tabla+'/'+campo+'/'+valor);
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'main/get/'+tabla+'/'+campo+'/'+valor,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',


    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        //alert("Funciona en el select estado");
        select.empty();
        select.append('<option selected disabled value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        select.append('<option value="'+data[i]['id']+'">'+data[i][1]+'</option>');

    };

    })
    .fail(function() {
        //alert("Error en el select "+idSelect);
    })
    .always(function() {

    });

}
```

Comment: Es una funcion que hace una llamada Ajax.  La linea que indicas es el URL a donde la llamada se va a efectuar.  En este caso, los parametros de la funcion son usados para formar dicho URL.

Comment: En estricto rigor, no tienes problemas con el codigo. No se si stackoverflow sirva para esto. En fin. La linea que indicas, solo esta armando (concatenando) la URL del request por ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Es un metodo por parametros de referencia que ejecuta un servicio AJAX, para ejecutarlo,
debes pasarle los parametros, en este caso son 4, tres hacen referencia a la url o ruta donde dispara ajax para ejecutar algun lenguage de backend (supongo). variables: tabla, campo, y valor. El idselector hace referencia a un id del DOM el cual es comvertido en un objeto con la ayuda de jquery var select = $('#'+idSelect);, para luego dejar en vacio el DOM select.empty();, i despues con append insertar etiquetas al DOM. Cabe recalcar que el ultimo proceso se realiza despues de que se halla ejecutado AJAX, trayendo consigo una variable data que posee la respuesta a la petición.